# Can't get all data out of my JSON

Tags: iphone, json, tableview, master-detail

I'm parsing a JSON to my MASTER-DETAIL app and having problem when "diggin deeper" into the JSON. I can't get data in my `detailTableView`.
In my `detailTableView`, I want to have the name of, in this case, the hotels/pousadas.

See my JSON and detailTableView.m:

```
[

    {
      "title": "Where to stay",
      "pousadas": 
     [
        {
            "beach": "Arrastão",
            "name": "Hotel Arrastão",
            "address": "Avenida Dr. Manoel Hipólito Rego 2097",
            "phone": "+55(12)3862-0099",
            "Email": "hotelarrastao_reserva@hotmail.com",
            "image": "test.jpg",
            "latitude": "-23.753355",
            "longitude": "-45.401946"
       }
    ]
  }

]
```

And the tableView in detailTableView.m:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return self.stayGuide.count;
}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"detailCellStay"];
```

Here are my tryouts:

```
    NSString *pous = [self.stayGuide valueForKey:@"name"];

    NSLog([self.stayGuide valueForKey:@"name"]);

    cell.textLabel.text = pous;



    return cell;
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You have an array of one element containing a dictionary with two elements -- "title" and "pousadas".  "pousadas" is, in turn, an array containing one element.  That one element is a dictionary containing the rest of the data.  Peel the onion, one layer at a time.  (And NSLog is your friend -- it will present a view of the intermediate data that looks very much like the original JSON, making it easy to see what you need to do next at each step.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're reading the JSON incorrectly!  Let's take a look at your data:

```
[ <---- array
    { <---- dictionary
        "title": "Where to stay",
        "pousadas": [ <---- array
            { <---- dictionary
                "beach": "Arrastão",
                "name": "Hotel Arrastão",
                "address": "Avenida Dr. Manoel Hipólito Rego 2097",
                "phone": "+55(12)3862-0099",
                "Email": "hotelarrastao_reserva@hotmail.com",
                "image": "test.jpg",
                "latitude": "-23.753355",
                "longitude": "-45.401946"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Suppose you have the data stored in the "stayGuide" property (which should be of type NSArray), you can access the initial dictionary like so:

```
NSDictionary *initialDictionary = [self stayGuide][0]; // access using new Objective-C literals
```

Now, you can access various values in here, such as the "pousadas" array.

```
NSArray *pousadas = initialDictionary[@"pousadas"];
```

Now, like we did with the initial dictionary, we can access the first object in the pousadas array.

```
NSDictionary *dictionary = pousadas[0];
```

Finally, we can access some of these keys within the first pousadas dictionary.

```
NSString *beach = dictionary[@"beach"];
NSString *name = dictionary[@"name"];
NSString *address = dictionary[@"address"];

NSLog(@"Beach: %@, Name: %@, Address: %@"beach,name,address);
```

In the future, though, you're probably going to want the stayGuide property to be equal to the pousadas array.  You could set it like so (where initialJSONArray is your starting JSON data):

```
[self setStayGuide:initialJSONArray[0][@"pousadas"]];
```

Comment: Saved my day @Aaron Wojnowski. Very pedagogic too!